# Как склонить Ф.И.О. в родительный падеж?

Tags: алгоритм, php

```
$fio = "Иванов Иван Иванович";
```

Есть ли алгоритм склонения Ф.И.О. на PHP в родительный падеж?

Нащёл алгоритмы склонения Ф.И.О., но не в родительном падеже или не для PHP. В идеале лучше 2 разных решения (попроще и посложнее).

Comment: Не стоит забывать что женские фамилии не склоняются.

Comment: как это не склоняются?

Comment: Только некоторые. Например, Ковальчук. "Нет Ковальчука" (его), но "Нет Ковальчук" (её).

Comment: Я и не писал, что буду склонять только мужские ФИО. еще, к стати, не склоняются всякие украинские фамилии типа "Абиджба".

Кода для склонения нет ни у кого?

Comment: http://ru.rodovid.org/wk/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0:%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0_%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%A4%D0%98%D0%9E

просвещайтесь

Comment: Класс позволяющий склонять русские имена, фамилии и отчества по падежам: https://web.archive.org/web/20120106221348/http://validweb.ru/threads/18

Comment: @mixalef При всем уважении, [Роман Абиджба](https://vk.com/abidzhba_romantrener) - россиянин...

Answer (score 1):

мне эта тема тоже интересна. скопировал первый код, дописал с низу:

```
$r = new NCLNameCaseRu();
$r->setLastName('Черепаншин');
$r->setFirstName('Рафаэль');
$r->setFatherName('Микельанжелович');
$r->setGender(1);
echo $r->getFormatted(2);
```

аналогично: Черепаншина Рафаэль Микельанжелович.

Comment: т.е. склоняется фамилия. и всё

Comment: Пол правильный выставьте ... $r->setGender(0);

Comment: пол правильный. это просто я первый раз опечатку допустил. получается: Черепаншину Рафаэль Микельанжелович

Comment: а у меня ок всё ...

Answer (score 1):

Кодировка с файлом класса должна быть в ANSI.
Класс вызываем следующим образом:

```
include ("NCLNameCaseRu.php");
$r = new NCLNameCaseRu();
$r->setFirstName(iconv('cp1251', 'utf-8', 'Иван'));
$r->setLastName(iconv('cp1251', 'utf-8', 'Иванов'));
$r->setFatherName(iconv('cp1251', 'utf-8', 'Иванович'));
$r->setGender(0);
echo iconv('utf-8', 'cp1251', $r->getFormatted(2));
```

При условии что документ где вызывается класс у нас в cp1251 кодировке. Проверенно, все работает!

Comment: вопрос я давно решил, но вот про то как подключить и юзать файл в другой кодировке буду знать. не бережете вы себя товарищ, на форуме, да в выходной!